# Auto reply to user is working but no email to admin in contact us

Tags: 7, emails

I want to use contact us form in my website but it is not working. I searched on Google and found many answers but they seems not relevant to me.

I have setup the contact us page and I can see the auto reply to my test email id (GMail) however my website is hosted on some other server, and they have provided the mail box to me.

I can send email directly from the mail box provided by hosting company to GMail. I can also send email from GMail to this mail box. Also I can see the auto reply email after submitting contact us form to my test GMail but I don't see any email to my mail box.

Edit: Just now, I discovered that if I configure GMail id as form submission recipient and then submit form with my hosting mail box email id, I am able to get the email from Drupal. In this case, I am not getting any auto reply to my hosting mail box.

What's wrong here? As I don't see any error in Drupal Log.

Comment: Have you checked the outgoing mail logs and incoming spam folder?

Comment: @Clive: Outgoing mail logs! Where? Hosting company has provided `roundcube` webclient and I checked the spam (Junk) folder already.

Comment: I couldn't say, just ask your provider how to access them. That'll tell you whether the problem is with Drupal not trying to send the emails, or with the mail server trying to deliver them

Comment: @Clive: Please check the `Edit`. I am able to send email from the hosting server mailbox to Gmail and vice a versa BUT it seems that Drupal is not able to send email to hosting email server mail box. Isn't it?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the logs really

Comment: @Clive: Can you explain a bit more? what kind of log you wanna see?